# Postgresql 9.3 log only insert, delete and update

Tags: postgresql, logging

I want to only log queries that modify tables (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE) while ignoring all SELECTs and its equivalents.

However, in the documentation, my options are to log ddl, ddl+mod or all in the log_statement line of the postgresql.conf file.

Is there some way to log into files all queries that manipulate data by changing settings of the configuration file or will I have to use some outside script or log to tables?

My current settings on my postgresql.conf, which still logs SELECT queries, are as follow:

```
log_destination = 'syslog, csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_statement = mod
```

Comment: I think the only option you have is to use `mod` which includes DDL statements. If there aren't too many DDL statements you should be able to filter them out (usually there are far fewer DDL statements than DML statements).

Comment: Unfortunately, my logs fill up with a near infinity of SELECTs and SETs, which gobbled up nearly 100GB in a few hours. This is the main reason I need these ignored.

Comment: `select` should not be logged when you use `mod`

Comment: You might also want to try `pg_stat_statements`: http://www.depesz.com/2014/10/14/what-logging-has-least-overhead/

Comment: I took a look at `pg_stat_statements`, but it seems it doesn't offer a straight filter for specific queries. It will keep a log of `pg_stat_statements.max` queries at any given time, so I'd have to set both a trigger to delete eventual SELECT queries as well as one to dump and reset it when it reaches its limit.
Also, it lacks a timestamp of when the query was run

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW log_statement` when connected to the DB you're using for your app, as the user you're using for your app. `mod` does *not* log `SELECT`s, so something else must be going on here. Please show some sample log lines in an edit to your question along with the output I just requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name and Craig pointed out, `log_statement = mod` shouldn't be logging select statements.

My problem was `log_min_duration_statement = 0`, which was acting as an AND, so to say (log this AND that). I've commented the log_min_duration out and now it is only logging what I actually needed.